# Ghost blog theme Casper - social sharing buttons are missing

Tags: jquery, ghost-blog, ghost

After migrating to Ghost 1.0 and Casper 2.0 (I'm actually on Ghost Version 1.13.0 and Casper Version 2.1.4), social sharing buttons are completely missing.

At first I thought they had been removed from the theme, since they usually have been on the footer. Instead they are inside an hidden `floating-header` div on the top of the page that is hidden by default, and should become visible after some scroll on the page.

It seems to be a javascript conflict that prevents the function that change the CSS from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I discover the problem was a conflict with the jquery `<script>` tag left in the [Code Injection](https://dev.ghost.org/no-more-jquery/) screen since Ghost 0.7 version.

Just remove the jquery `<script>` tag to fix the problem and have back the `floating-header` div with social sharing buttons.

[image: Code Injection screenshot]